# Track WebDriver requests with Fiddler or so

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, vpn

I am creating a web scraper application using C# and Selenium with Chrome WebDriver. So far I have configured it like this:

```
public class Program
{
    private static ChromeOptions options;
    private static ChromeDriver driver;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var proxy = new Proxy();
        proxy.Kind = ProxyKind.Manual;
        proxy.IsAutoDetect = false;
        proxy.HttpProxy = "127.0.0.1.fiddler:52840";
        
        options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.Proxy = proxy;
        options.AddArgument("ignore-certificate-errors");
        options.SetLoggingPreference(LogType.Driver, LogLevel.All);
        
        driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.google.com");
    }
}
```

But I can't seem to get any info in Fiddler while accessing "https://www.google.com".
I am also wondering - if I install an application on my PC (I am using Windows 10 Pro) which enables VPN while browsing, will this VPN be active while scraping or I need a manual configuration in the WebDriver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default fiddler will set Internet Options to use proxy and Chrome will follow it so there is no need to set it in your code. things to check:

1. Check Fiddler listen port: `Tools > Options > Connections > Fiddler listens on ports`
2. make sure `127.0.0.1.fiddler` valid local domain or use local IP `127.0.0.1`
3. Disable IPv6

Comment: Hello @ewwink. Fiddler listens to port **8888**. I have removed the proxy configuration part from my code and disabled IPv6. But I wasn't able to find out if `127.0.0.1:fiddler` is a valid local domain, because I don't know how. Now when I acces a website with Selenium, I can see the traffic in Fiddler. Thank you!

Comment: Hmmm, I am a bit confused - if Fiddler stays as a proxy, shouldn't it change my IP to the rest of the world? With or without this software I end up using one and the same IP.

Comment: your public IP will not change and if fiddler closed it will restored to default internet option.